# How do I know when there are no more results from Google Datastore Java Library

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

Using the `com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreReader.java` class (v1.3.1) to execute queries to Google Cloud Datastore, how do I know when there are no more results? I noticed that I keep getting a Cursor back even when it seems there are no results left.

Am I guaranteed to get an iterator **with values** back if there are values left as a result of my query?

Am I guaranteed to get number of elements specified with the Limit on the query back if there are enough elements left in the query result set?

```
    QueryResults<Entity> queryResults = null;
    do {
        final EntityQuery query = newEntityQueryBuilder()
            .setKind(ENTITY_KIND)
            .setLimit(50)
            .setStartCursor((null!=queryResults)?queryResults.getCursorAfter():Cursor.copyFrom(new byte[0]))
            .build();

        queryResults = datastore.run(query);

        queryResults.forEachRemaining(entity -> {
            // Some operations
        });

    } while ( ??? );
```

Comment: Have you tried using `queryResults.hasNext()` to check if there is, at least, an element?

Answer (score 0):

Below approach can be used.

```
Datastore datastore = dataStoreService.getDatastore();
    StructuredQuery<Entity> query = 
Query.newEntityQueryBuilder().setKind(KIND_NAME).build();
     QueryResults<Entity> results = datastore.run(query);
    while (results.hasNext()) {
        Entity entity = results.next();
        //use ObjectMapper to convert Datastore information to domain object and add to list 
    }
  //return list
```